# ComboBox for values in different rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help with a combo box in FormOne that shows values from TableOne based on the value: ID. 
Below illustrates a sample of TableOne:

```
ID          Name           Adress
1
1
1           Tom       
1                           Streetname 1    
2
2
2           Steve 
2                           Streetname2 
2
```

I need help with a combo box and related text field that are only showing the relevant information based on the ID record.

Does anyone have any clever solution for this ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. --- If you have a continuous form and want a combobox to show different values in different rows, that's not how continuous forms work.

Comment: I want a combo box that looks up the values (no blanks) based the ID, so that is possible to edit the name and address. Don know if this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query as source:

```
SELECT 
    TableOne.ID, 
    TableOne_1.Name, 
    TableOne_2.Address
FROM 
    (TableOne 
LEFT JOIN 
    TableOne AS TableOne_1 
        ON TableOne.ID = TableOne_1.ID) 
LEFT JOIN 
    TableOne AS TableOne_2 
        ON TableOne.ID = TableOne_2.ID
GROUP BY 
    TableOne.ID, 
    TableOne_1.Name, 
    TableOne_2.Address
HAVING 
    TableOne_1.Name Is Not Null 
    AND 
    TableOne_2.Address Is Not Null;
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav for the help !! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please marked as answered if it did fit.